# WooCommerce: Single-product-postslug template not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

First,I know wordpress won't  allow you to use template for posts (WooCommerce's product page is built via post). So I look for the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).
It says there:

> `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` (Since 4.4). First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post.
>
> For example, if post type is product and the post slug is `dmc-12`, WordPress would look for `single-product-dmc-12.php`.
>
> `single-{post-type}.php` – If the post type is product, WordPress would look for `single-product.php`.
> `single.php` – WordPress then falls back to `single.php`.
> `singular.php` – Then it falls back to `singular.php`.
> `index.php` – Finally, as mentioned above, WordPress ultimately falls back to `index.php`.

So I created a template and name it `single-product-ccc` (ccc is one of my product's slug name), but nothing happened, nothing was affected. 
But by creating a template named single-product will affect all of the product pages.

Why is that happening?

I don't get it. Even a `single-2313.php` (**`2313`** is one post's id) will overwrite the default `single.php` for that **`2313`** post.

Why single-product-slug is not working in the same way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first correct you at one point. You say: "WooCommerce's product page is built via post".

This is not correct. WooCommerce creates a new post type 'product'. You can see all custom posts types that WooCommerce creates here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/

The 'product' post type uses the template *single-product.php*.

As you say, [WordPress Template Hierarchy Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) say that you can create a template for a particular product:

> single-{post-type}-{slug}.php (Since 4.4). First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for single-product-dmc-12.php.

WooCommerce is a WordPress plugin and as so, it doesn't always follow WordPress rules strictly, and this is one of those cases. But you can use a filter to correct this very easily. In your theme's functions.php simply add:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_single_product_template_include', 50, 1 );

function custom_single_product_template_include( $template ) {
     if ( is_singular('product')  && (get_the_ID()==30)) {
           $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-30.php';
     } 
     return $template;
}
```

where *get_the_ID()* is the id of your Product. Now, you can create a new template as for example single-product-30.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in functions.php

```
function your_theme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_theme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

and now onwards, you can use woocommerce/single-product.php for customisation